# Is there a good way to include a Rails asset stylesheet in a WordPress theme?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, wordpress-theming, asset-pipeline

I'm developing a site in Rails 4, but we are using WordPress for blogging and content management. Is there a good, reliable way I can link to the current Rails asset CSS (the fingerprinted, production version) from within WordPress?

I'm currently contemplating scanning the public/assets dir for the most recently updated css file, but I was hoping someone had thought of a better solution.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here.  Application.css gets called in your application.html.erb template, which is applied to every page of your project.  Why do you need to link to it again?

Comment: I want to link to it in WordPress. The URI is something like /assets/application-a53d20435e79294e7afba8677ce3d602.css and changes when the CSS changes. I want my custom WordPress theme to use that for its CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Editing my solution since it's not any better than yours. Here's my update:

You could just not digest it and not get the variable fingerprint. Since you're using Rails 4.0 you can't just `:digest => false` your asset. But you can install the following gem which will allow you to output a file which you can include from outside of your Rails app.

[non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets)